# Selenium-webdriver. Браузер Opera не запускается (выдает ошибку)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

Подскажите пожалуйста, как запустить тест в Node.js через браузер Opera.Скачивал operadriver и прописывал в Path, не помогает. Может есть у кого пример запуска теста в Opera.

> WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Opera binary
>     (Driver info: OperaDriver=2.30,platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Answer (score 2):

У драйвера Оперы есть [давняя проблема](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/9) (которую разработчики, похоже, проблемой не считают): требуется явно указать путь до исполняемого файла самой Оперы. О том, как это сделать, документации в явном виде не нашел. Похоже, работает следующий код:

```js
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

const caps = webdriver.Capabilities.opera();
caps.set('chromeOptions', {
  binary: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Opera/49.0.2725.34/opera.exe'
});

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('opera')
  .withCapabilities(caps)
  .build();

driver.get('https://google.com/');
driver.sleep(5000);
driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка заключается в том, что у вас на машине, на которой вы пытаетесь запустить тесты, не установлен сам браузер Opera.

operadriver это всего лишь "прослойка" между кодом и самим браузером.

Установите на машину Opera.